.net 3.1 and dotnet 6 on ubuntu 22.04 issue [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not exist
I've Ubuntu 22.04
I've successfully install .net core 3.1
using this way
How can I install dotnet Core 3.1 runtime on Ubuntu 22.04?
and it's work perfectly
then I treid to install .net 6
using this way first
but It's did not work for me and nothnig happend with me after trying
dontet --list-sdks 

the version is 3.1 alone
after that I followed
this way from docs
by calling those commands
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh
./dotnet-install.sh --version 6.0.421

after that when I'm trying
dotnet --list-sdks

I'm facing this error
Error: [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not exist


As you would have read in the second link, installing by script is NOT recommended. The method given seems pretty much like Microsoft's recommendation, but you don't say what went wrong. You say you installed per the docs, but that's not Microsoft's recommended way either. Those instructions are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-install?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu-2204&tabs=dotnet8

did you install 3.1 using my instructions?  I wonder if dotnet points to something local (eg in your home directory rather than a system install) and then your dotnet 6 is installed system wide.  You could determine where dotnet is coming from by using which dotnet.  Unfortunately I've never installed more than one dotnet on linux and not sure how to use the obsolete 3.1 in combination with a newer one

further thoughts - it might be worth installing another newer version of .net (I assume there's newer than 6 now? I've not used it for a long time at this point) and seeing what changes in the system wide install directory - possibly you could make a git or similar repo in there and commit the current contents first so you can see exactly what changes.  I'm wondering whether it might as easy as just merging the folders between installs to get different versions but this is basically just guess work.

Also other thing would be to avoid 3.1 if possible since it's out of support.  I assume you need to use both an old one and a newer one - a simple solution might be to adjust your path depending on what project you're working on... again that's on the assumption that the problem is that you have 2 separate install locations

Try this first I just noticed there's a potentially helpful comment on my answer in the other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428117/how-can-i-install-dotnet-core-3-1-runtime-on-ubuntu-22-04/1482285?noredirect=1#comment2649887_1482285  - pgampe gives instructions on where to copy it to translate local to a system install

As Auspex suggests I think you'd be better off installing dotnet from your package repo unless there's a good reason not to.  From those docs it looks like .net 6 is still supported
